# Implementing voting or "likes" using MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, database

I am creating a system where users (who are identified by a user id number) will be allowed to vote on posts (think Reddit, StackOverflow, etc).

Users can vote a post up or not vote at all on it.

The number of votes on a given post can easily be stored within the table containing the posts.

Keeping track of who has voted, however, is a different task entirely that I'm not sure how to approach.

I was thinking I could have a table that would have two columns: user id and post id.

When they vote on a post, I add their user id and post id to that table. If they unvote, I remove that entry from the table.

EG:

```
User ID | Post ID
1       | 3949
1       | 4093 
2       | 3949
etc...
```

Is this a reasonable solution?

Comment: "Is this a reasonable solution?" yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is reasonably simple and easy solution to the problem. You can do the same for your comments(if you like to). In your MAIN_POST table assign a post_id and use this same post_id in other tables (comments(post_id, user_id, post_comment, comment_time) and votes(post_id, user_id, vote_status(you can use 1 for vote up and 0 for vote down))). It will complicate your sql queries, to retrieve data, a little but you can do it. And on android side there are alot of tricks to handle and furnish this data in application and you can make this vote(like) and comments idea just like facebook (YOU for your comments and likes and NAMES for others).

Answer (score 0):

Using an 'in between' or 'joining' table is a perfectly acceptable solution in this case. If relevant you could even add a timestamp to the relation and show to the user *when* a user has upvoted something.

Also it is important to take care of proper Indexes and Keys to have your table structure also perform properly once the dataset grows.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove rows from the table.  I understand why you would want to do that, but why lose the information?  Instead, keep a +1/-1 value for each entry and then sum up the values for a post:

```
select sum(vote)
from uservotes
where postid = 1234;
```

And, I agree with Rick that you should also include the creation date/time.